# The `.key` is coming out as undefined. What do I do to make it come out as an actual ASCII representation?

Tags: javascript

This comes out as undefined. Why is this?

```js
var possibleKeyCodes = [ 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90 ];

console.log(possibleKeyCodes[0].key);
```

I expected it to give me a key name as a string. It just gave me an `undefined`.

Comment: Since when do numbers have a `key` property? What “key name” are you talking about?

Comment: Why have you added `.key` at the end?

Comment: You mean the [`key`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) from a keyboard event? Consider using the [`code`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) property of such an event, or even better, the `data` property of an [`input` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/InputEvent#instance_properties). Other than that, this is a duplicate of [How to create a string or char from an ASCII value in JavaScript?](/q/602020/4642212).

Comment: I now realize that this post is a duplicate. I cannot delete it, but I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var possibleKeyCodes = [ 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90 ];

console.log(possibleKeyCodes[0].key);
```

Your array is an array of numbers. You are trying to treat an element of this array as it is an object with `key` property

If you need the ascii repreentation of that number you can do it like that

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(possibleKeyCodes[0]))
```

Or as a snippet

```js
var possibleKeyCodes = [ 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90 ];
console.log(String.fromCharCode(possibleKeyCodes[0]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Key ? WHat is Key ???
What is your need ?  value or Index ?
To get the value inside an array this way is ok

```
console.log(possibleKeyCodes[0]) // 65
console.log(possibleKeyCodes[1]) // 66
console.log(possibleKeyCodes[5]) // 70
```

for get index of value

```
console.log(possibleKeyCodes.findIndex(x=>x==65));
```

Comment: He is trying to convert a number from the array to its corresponding ascii representation . For example 65 => 'A'